# Text animated slider with loop

Tags: jquery, animation, text

I would like to create a text loop, like a slider which is vertical. So i've seen this effects one on a someones portfolio, can't really remember when. I made a gif image with preview of how it would look like just a lot slower:

[image: animated text]

```
<p>This is some example</p> <h1>Text</h1> <h1>Text 2</h1> <h1>Text 3</h1>
```

In which way could I animate it without using plug-ins and sliders. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Here's an example that probably needs some additional work, but should hopefully get you started.

http://jsfiddle.net/YbDq3/1/

jQuery

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('h1').css({top: 40, opacity: 0});
    scrollWord();
});

function scrollWord() {
    $('h1').last().animate({top: 7, opacity: 1}, 200, 'linear', function() {
        $(this).animate({top: -20, opacity: 0}, 200, 'linear', function() {
            $(this).css({top: 40, opacity: 0});
            $('p').after($(this));
            scrollWord();
        });
    });
}
```

CSS

```
h1 {font-size: inherit; padding: 0; display: inline-block; font-weight: normal; margin: 0 0 0 5px; position: absolute;}
p {margin: 0; padding: 0; display: inline-block;}
```

HTML

```
<p>This is some example</p><h1>Text</h1><h1>Text2</h1><h1>Text3</h1>
```

Hope it helps!

Comment: I found solution for my problem but it's still isn't simple jquery code, I used two plug-ins and I don't like using plug-ins. Here is the final result at the top: http://dupovacemir.com/